# Can elasticsearch return all facets if no facets are returned with a facet filter?

Tags: filter, elasticsearch, facet

I am currently using elasticsearch in combination with the rubberband gem to index items from a online catalogue. My use case is as follows:

An item can have multiple subitems, e.g. a comic book with multiple stories in it. These stories are indexed as a nested document in the items document and has three specific features. A story:

- has one or multiple writers
- has one or multiple illustrators
- is part of a serie or has zero or multiple heroes.

I am applying facets on these three features and am adding a facet filter if the user has given a search term. The given search term is also used to query the whole index. Sometimes a user is searching on a specific story in a comic book. If so, I want the facets to return the writers, illustrators and series of that specific story, and not the facets of the whole comic book, but there is no way to know this in advance. The user just fills in a search term and doesn't make a distinction between searching on a comic book or searching on a story. I have thought of the following sollution for this problem:

- If the given search term returns facets when applied to the facet filter, then I assume the user is searching for a story in a comic book and the facets can be returned
- If the given search term returns no facets when applied to the facet filter, then I assume the user is searching for a comic book itself and the filter must be removed to return facets.

I want to know if there is a possibility in elasticsearch to tell the facet filter to remove itself if no facets are returned?

Answer (score 0):

You could simply add each facet twice, once with a facet filter, and once without?

Comment: That's one possible solution. Only it turns out the problem is a little more complex than how I described it. After letting some user test it, it turned out that in some cases a facet with a filter was returned, when in fact the user was searching for a comic instead of a story within a comic. I have to look for some other criteria to decide when a user is searching for a comic book or a story within a comic book.

Answer (score 0):

I'm reading two questions, to answer the first: if you want to return facets with zero-count as well, you could use `all_terms: true` in your query like in this example (taken from the [elasticsearch reference](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-facets-terms-facet.html#_all_terms)):

```
{
    "query" : {
        "match_all" : {  }
    },
    "facets" : {
        "tag" : {
            "terms" : {
                "field" : "tag",
                "all_terms" : true
            }
        }
    }
}
```

(This solution requires that you have access to the raw query. If it is hidden behind some logic of the rubberband gem, you would have to check if you could set this property there.)

I'm afraid an assumed solution to your second question ("Is there a possibility to tell the facet filter to remove itself if no facets are returned") would make it hard to determine between **actual results** and **results, although there were none in the first place**.